# Why did Lot choose to flee to Zoar instead of the mountains as the angel instructed?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 19:17-20, NIV

> As soon as they had brought them out, one of them said, “Flee for
> your lives! Don’t look back, and don’t stop anywhere in the plain!
> Flee to the mountains or you will be swept away!”

> But Lot said to them, “No, my lords, please!
> Your servant has found favor in your eyes, and you
> have shown great kindness to me in sparing my life. But I can’t flee
> to the mountains; this disaster will overtake me, and I’ll die.
> Look, here is a town near enough to run to, and it is small. Let me
> flee to it—it is very small, isn’t it? Then my life will be spared.”

Comment: This  is a good example of an "opinion-based" question that should be welcomed. Even though it can be answered in more than one way, it is not a subject of serious controversy and readers benefit by considering various approaches to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Lot loved the world, and did not want to leave the cities of the plain, known for wealth and urban comfort. Note how he hesitated when it was time to go, and the angels needed to grab him and force him to leave:

> And while he lingered, the men laid hold upon his hand, and upon the
> hand of his wife, and upon the hand of his two daughters; the Lord
> being merciful unto him: and they brought him forth, and set him
> without the city. Gen 19.16

Zoar was the smallest of the five cities, which communicated with each other and shared social and economic ties. All five were doomed to destruction, but as with Sodom, God waited until Lot left before destroying it.

So like many when confronted with the destruction of their life, he tried to negotiate and salvage some of it:  Can I have this little city? It's such a small city!

Lot had a position of honor in Sodom ("Lot sat in the gate of Sodom" 19.1). The gate of the city is where the leaders "sat" to pronounce judgement on matters and officiate proceedings (see Ruth 4.1-8 for an example of such a proceeding). So Lot would then be in a position to also be honored in Zoar, even if it was just a little of the honor he had in Sodom.

It is a sad story of Lot, who started out so wealthy he needed to separate from Abraham, was given the choice of going anywhere he wanted, and ended up losing his wealth, his wife, his honor, his comfortable urban home, and ended up hiding in the hills, sleeping in a cave, being raped by his own daughters.

Comment: Robert,  Very good insight why Lot could only go so far.

Comment: Thanks, @Sherrie. The story of Lot is dear to me.

Comment: Lot showed a lack of faith in God's wisdom in the angel's command to flee to the mountains, which didn't work out too well for him.

Answer (score 0):

Genesis 19:

> 18But Lot said to them, “No, my lords, please! 19Your servant has found favor in your eyes, and you have shown great kindness to me in sparing my life. But I can’t flee to the mountains; this disaster will overtake me, and I’ll die. 20Look, here is a town **near** enough to run to, and it is **small**. Let me flee to it—it is very small, isn’t it? Then my life will be spared.”

Why did Lot choose to flee to Zoar instead of the mountains as the angel instructed?

Lot didn't want to exert so much effort to flee to the mountain. The town was nearby so he begged the angles. This way, he minimized the time and effort to reach safety.

Answer (score 0):

Examining several [rabbinical commentaries](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.20?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=en) about this, there are a couple that are worth considering here:

- Hezekiah ben Manoah says that the fire and brimstone were already very close. Lot felt he did not have time to get to the mountains, and he had a better chance of find shelter in Zoar.
- Radak and Ben Haim say the little town of Zoar was not as evil as Sodom and Gomorrah, by virtue of its small size or more recent founding. Lot was asking that this town would be spared so that he could find shelter there.

Several other opinions are given, but these two work well for me.